# difference for Locale.autoupdatingCurrent and fixed Locale behavior

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, dateformatter, ios16

If I use system locale (Locale.autoupdatingCurrent) then DateFormatter uses 24 switch in system settings.

```
let locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent;
let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0*3600)!
var calendar = Calendar.current;
calendar.locale = locale;
calendar.timeZone = timeZone;
let iso:ISO8601DateFormatter = .init();
iso.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime];
let date = iso.date(from: "2000-01-01T13:16:45Z")!
let df:DateFormatter = .init()
df.locale = locale
df.timeZone = timeZone
df.timeStyle = .medium        
let s = df.string(from: date)
print(s) // 1:16:45 pm
// switch to 24 Hour time in system settings
print(s) // 13:16:45
```

But if I use a fixed locale and manually set hourCycle, then DateFormatter ignores this attribute.

```
var components = Locale.Components(languageCode: "en", languageRegion: "GB")
components.hourCycle = .oneToTwelve
let locale = Locale(components: components)
// .... above code
print(s) // 13:16:45 for oneToTwelve hourCycle
```

Comment: This only seems to be the case of en_GB.  I tried en_US and en_AU and got the expected behaviour - ie. always 1:16:45 pm. It also returns 13:16:45 for fr_FR, de_at but not for en_ca.  It seems that Europe always gets 24 hour time?

Comment: @Paulw11 what about set hourCycle to .zeroToTwentyThree for en_US?

Comment: Indeed, all of those locales I mentioned give a 12 hour am/pm time, regardless of device local and regardless of the `hourCycle`

Answer (score 0):

[`Locale.Components`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/components) and as such [`Locale.init(components:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/3952514-init) and also [`Locale.hourCycle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/4020219-hourcycle) are all new APIs for iOS 16 and macOS 13 which the legacy parts of `Foundation` like `DateFormatter` don't seem to understand/respect (yet?).

Unfortunately, not even the new [`Date.formatted(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3766587-formatted) with [`Date.FormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle) from iOS 15 and macOS 12 support it, so I'm starting to suspect that `.hourCycle` is just meant to be used as a handy read-only property and not actually for customizing date-time format.

It seems like `Locale.current` and `.autoupdatingCurrent` use some hidden internal way of checking the 12h/24h override in the user's settings because if you inspect `_componentsBox.wrapped.hourCycle` with the Debugger, you will see that it will be always `nil` regardless of the user's settings.
This is different from `Locale.init(components:)` instances which will have this value correctly set if you've overridden it with `Locale.Components.hourCycle`.

However, reading the `Locale.hourCycle` property will return the correct value for all three kinds of `Locale` instances.

If you want to force 12h/24h format in `DateFormatter`, you will have to do something like this:

```swift
let locale = ...

let template: String = {
    switch locale.hourCycle {
        case .zeroToEleven: fallthrough
        case .oneToTwelve: return "hh"
        case .zeroToTwentyThree: fallthrough
        case .oneToTwentyFour: return "HH"
    }
}() + "mmss"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = locale
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(template)
```

I don't think it's possible to force this with the new `Date.formatted(_:)` however. See:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701972